# Can't put angular-foundation typeahead above other foundation-apps grid-block

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation, typeahead.js

See the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PZRCmbyCxwMU9aAgtybX?p=preview) (better with smaller screen).

I'm using [foundation-apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/grid) with grid-blocks generated by `ng-repeat`. The inputs are using [angular-foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) typeahead. When you type an 'a' in one of the input, the dropdown will appear strictly within its grid-block. Consequently I obtain a scroll bar while I would like to see the dropdown above everything else...

A z-index does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution, thanks to the Foundation team. The details are in this [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6464).

An `overflow: visible` instead of `overflow: auto` for grid-block allows me to see the dropdown list above everything else.